# Coldfusion-2018 HTTP Token: Access denied

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-2016

The cURL (cfhttp) command in Coldfusion-10 worked, but after migrating the same code to Coldfusion-2018 is not working.

I have the below code working on CF10.

```
<cfset 
structContainer = {
    "container": {
        "number": "ABCD123456",
        "shipping_line": "ABCD",
        "sandbox_url": "http://api.myhost.com/"
    }
}/>

<cfset structJson = serializeJSON(structContainer) />

<cfhttp
    url="https://customerurl/api/v1/"
    method="post"
    result="structResult"
    username="myaccount@myhost.com"
    password="12345">

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Token token=x1x2x3x4x5x6">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-ApiVersion" value="1.0">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="*/*">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" encoded="false" value="#trim(structJson)#">
</cfhttp>


<html>
    <body>
        <cfoutput>
            <cfdump
                var="#structResult#"
                label="HTTP Body"
                output="c:/result.txt"
            />
        </cfoutput>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I migrated to Coldfusion 2018 is returning the error below (structResult):

```
HTTP Body - struct

Charset: utf-8
Errordetail: [empty string]
Filecontent: HTTP Token: Access denied.
Header: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 12:56:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
WWW-Authenticate: Token realm="Application"
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 4539026e-8b8d-4f67-836b-153b8b9c58fc
X-Runtime: 0.006391
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Mimetype: text/html
Responseheader:  
    [struct]
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 12:56:48 GMT
    Explanation: Unauthorized
    Http_Version: HTTP/1.1
    Status_Code: 401
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    WWW-Authenticate: Token realm="Application"
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Request-Id: 4539026e-8b8d-4f67-836b-153b8b9c58fc
    X-Runtime: 0.006391
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Statuscode: 401 Unauthorized
Text: YES
```

Please, someone to give me a light?

Best Regards!

Comment: I use the same Token value in CF-10 and CF-2018!!!

Comment: Did you import the certs?

Comment: It's difficult to speculate without having the real endpoint details to reproduce with. The SSL Certificates are worth checking, however the 401 is not what I would expect for an SSL trust issue. It seems more likely that the 401 is chosen by authentication logic on the side of the endpoint. Perhaps that endpoint is IP address restricted and your CF10 server was whitelisted in the past and you are running CF2018 on a different server with a different IP address? Or they prevent you from authenticating with the same credentials from different machines?